# Problem with NDSolve and Manipulate

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

I have an NDSolve expression working in stand alone fashion in a Manipulate. I cannot get the same NDSolve expression working in a Manipulate against a set of data points. My code will plot the data points in the Manipulate. My code will not plot the NDSolve expression in the same Manipulate. Here is my code (Do you see anything wrong?):

```
ClearAll[t, f2a, x0, v0, a1, f1, m1, c1, k0, k1, e1]

f2a[t_, x0_, v0_, a1_, f1_, m1_, c1_, k0_, k1_, e1_] := 
 xx[t] /. NDSolve[{m1 xx''[t] + 
      c1 xx'[t] + (k1 + (k0 - k1) Exp[-t e1]) xx[t] == 
     a1 Cos[f1 2 \[Pi] t], xx[0] == x0, xx'[0] == v0}, xx, {t, 0, 250}]

Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[f2a[t, x0, v0, a1, f1, m1, c1, k0, k1, e1], {t, 0, 250}, 
   Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.0, 250}, {-20.0, 10.0}}, 
   ImageSize -> {800, 509.3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thickness[0.01]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2.0/\[Pi], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time (months)", Bold, Blue], 
     Style["Amplitude ", Bold, Blue]}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]], pltMale50thIn50th, 
  pltMNoon50th], {{x0, 0.0, 
   Style["Initial (x0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -10.0, 10.0, 1.0, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{v0, 0.0, 
   Style["(Initial v0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -20.0, 20.0, 1.0, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Force a1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f1, 0.0, 
   Style["(Force f1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -0.0, 2.5, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Mass m1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.10, 5.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c1, 2.5, 
   Style["( DashPot c1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 5.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Elasticity k1 + (k0 - k1) exp(-e1 t)", Blue, Bold, 
  Medium], {{k0, 2.0, Style["(Elasticity k0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 
  0.25, 5.0, 0.250, ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Elasticity k1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.25, 5.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Elasticity e1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top, Paneled -> True, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

Comment: I'd suggest you take some time and read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users). It will give you a sold background to understand how Mathematica works.

Answer (score 2):

Plot has `HoldAll` attribute, which means that your function is not evaluated. To alleviate this , just wrap your function with `Evaluate` and it will work

```
ClearAll[t, f2a, x0, v0, a1, f1, m1, c1, k0, k1, e1]

f2a[t_, x0_, v0_, a1_, f1_, m1_, c1_, k0_, k1_, e1_] := 
 xx[t] /. NDSolve[{m1 xx''[t] + 
      c1 xx'[t] + (k1 + (k0 - k1) Exp[-t e1]) xx[t] == 
     a1 Cos[f1 2 \[Pi] t], xx[0] == x0, xx'[0] == v0}, xx, {t, 0, 250}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[f2a[t, x0, v0, a1, f1, m1, c1, k0, k1, e1]], {t, 0, 
   250}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0.0, 250}, {-20.0, 10.0}}, ImageSize -> {800, 509.3},
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thickness[0.01]}, 
  AspectRatio -> 2.0/\[Pi], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Time (months)", Bold, Blue], 
    Style["Amplitude ", Bold, Blue]}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]], {{x0, 0.0, 
   Style["Initial (x0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -10.0, 10.0, 1.0, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{v0, 0.0, 
   Style["(Initial v0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -20.0, 20.0, 1.0, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{a1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Force a1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f1, 0.0, 
   Style["(Force f1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -0.0, 2.5, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Mass m1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.10, 5.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c1, 2.5, 
   Style["( DashPot c1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 5.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter, 
 Style["Elasticity k1 + (k0 - k1) exp(-e1 t)", Blue, Bold, 
  Medium], {{k0, 2.0, Style["(Elasticity k0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 
  0.25, 5.0, 0.250, ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Elasticity k1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.25, 5.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e1, 1.0, 
   Style["(Elasticity e1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top, Paneled -> True, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

which gives

[image]

Besides this, you have two unknown variables within show. I removed `Show` completely.

Comment: Dear Mister (Professor) ercegovac- I followed your instructions. My NDSolve expression now works inside of my Manipulate. One question remains. How do I restore the data plots you removed? My goal is to hand fit the NDSolve expression against a set of data points (t,y) that I might be able to call upon NonlinearModelFit. Please clarify. Thank You.

Comment: Well, it should work if you just wrap them with `Show`. If there is an issue, try to create a minimum working example to illustrate the problem. Accept this answer if it's resolving your issue. Also, besides the previous link that i left in the comment under your question, I recommend you reading [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help) since you seam to be new to this website as well.

Comment: A thousand Thank You's Professor ercegovac! With your guidance I now have a Manipulate exactly to my needs! Thanks Again!